# Having a TableLayout Issue

Tags: java, swing, button, tablelayout

```
public void createWindow2(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src\\resources\\registerBg.png")));
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(false);


        double size[][] = {{TableLayout.FILL,70,10,200,TableLayout.FILL}, //COLUNAS
                {TableLayout.FILL,30,5,30,5,30,5,30,5,30,5,30,82.5,30,82.5}}; //LINHAS
        setLayout(new TableLayout(size));
```

(...)

```
//Botoes JPanel
            buts = new JPanel();
            double size2[][] = {{TableLayout.FILL,100,5,100,TableLayout.FILL}, //COLUNAS
                    {TableLayout.FILL}}; //LINHAS
            buts.setLayout(new TableLayout(size2));
            add(buts,"0,4,13,13");
                //Continuar
                continuar = new JButton("Continuar");
                buts.add(continuar,"1,0");
                //Voltar
                voltar =new JButton("Voltar");
                buts.add(voltar,"3,0");
```

Here is the image of this Frame running

http://oi42.tinypic.com/m83cko.jpg

I've been a lot of time tryin to find why the buttons dont appear, but i didn't find the reason, can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Java swing(its called to the visual code of the programing language "java")
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)

Comment: I know what Java and Swing are, but again what is JSwing? I've not seen that term used and I doubt that it really exists in this context. When asking questions here, strive to be accurate to avoid confusion.

Comment: Where have you downloaded TableLayout? What is the source of your library? It's not part of the standard Swing layouts, and likely has an API that goes with the library that can help you and us solve your problem.

Comment: Here is the link:
http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/Download.html

Comment: Thank you. "JSwing" deleted from your question title.

Answer (score -1):

Just thinking from the top of my head, but this code will work for you. It would appear you are adding the buttons incorrectly; at least from my perspective. The code below will work for you.

```
public class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JButton plainJButton;
}

public ButtonFrame() {
    plainJButton = new JButton( "Plain Button" );
    add( plainJButton );
}
```

Comment: That won't work because i set the frame layout to "TableLayout"[setLayout(new TableLayout(size));], and this layout works with arrays where you set the rows and lines of the frame, so when you add an object you need to specify in what row and line you want to add the it.
You can get more information about this layout here:
http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/index.html

Comment: Do you have to do it that way? LayoutManager (in package java.awt) is the sanctioned way to do it. Within that, you have **[GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)** which can accomplish something simliar to what you're looking for.

Comment: @kgdesouz: GridLayout would be terrible to use for this purpose, the tabular layout of label and text field. Much better would be GridBagLayout, GroupLayout, or MigLayout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: agreed, GroupLayout et al would be better here.  The point really was that LayoutManager in java.awt is the way to go.

Comment: @kgdesouz: not necessarily. I've found many situations where it is easier to use a 3rd party layout manager such as the MigLayout when creating such tabular data entry screens.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: good to know. thanks for the info, I'm looking it up now and learning.